# Use Lagrange Mean Value Theorem to prove that $|\tan^{-1}(x)-\tan^{-1}(y)| < |x-y| \forall x,y$ belongs to real number.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I used LMVT to establish that $(\tan^{-1}(x)-\tan^{-1}(y))/(y-x) = 1/1+c^2$
After that I'm stuck and don't know how to establish the given inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \tan^{-1}x$, then $f'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

WLOG, suppose that $x < y$.  By Mean Value Theorem, there exists $c \in (x,y)$ such that

$$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} = f'(c)$$

$$\frac{\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y}{x-y} = \frac{1}{1+c^2} \le 1$$

---

Edit in response to @Mucciolo's comment

If we have $c \ne 0$, then we're done.

Thus, assume, $c = 0$.  To avoid copying @zhw.'s solution, it's better to give an alternative solution by considering the *strictly increasing* function $h(t) = \tan t - t \;\forall t \in \left( -\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2 \right)$.

> $h'(t) = \sec^2 t - 1 > 0\;\forall |t| \in \left( 0,\frac\pi2 \right)$ so it's strictly increasing on $\left( -\frac\pi2,0 \right)$ and $\left( 0,\frac\pi2 \right)$.
>
> Let $s < 0 < t$.  Then there exists $\xi,\zeta$ with $s < \xi < 0 < \zeta < t$ such that
>   \begin{alignat}{2}
> \frac{h(s) - h(0)}{s-0} &= h'(\xi) > 0 &\quad \frac{h(t) - h(0)}{t-0} &= h'(\zeta) > 0 \\
> h(s) - h(0) &< 0 &\quad h(t) - h(0) &> 0
> \end{alignat}
>   So we have $h(s)<h(0)<h(t) \,\forall s < 0, t > 0$.  This shows that $h$ is *strictly* increasing, and thus *injective*.

Let $s = \tan^{-1} x$ and $t = \tan^{-1} y$.

\begin{align}
\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y &= x-y \\
s - t &= \tan s - \tan t \\
\tan s - s &= \tan t - t \\
h(s) &= h(t) \\
s &= t \quad (h \text{ is injective}) \\
\tan s &= \tan t \\
x &= y  \quad \text{(contradicts $x < y$)}
\end{align}

Comment: The inequality $ \frac{1}{1+c^2}<1 $ holds provided that $ c \neq 0 $. So the case where $ c = 0 $ still need to be addressed.

Comment: @Mucciolo Thanks for your comment (and I guess, downvote).  I've edited my answer in order to address the problem that you had raised.  Though the trick ("zero-in-the-middle") is the same as zhw.'s answer, I tried not copying his solution.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose WLOG $x<y.$ If $0\le x < y,$ then the MVT gives the result immediately as pointed out by @GNU Supporter. Same thing if $x<y\le 0.$ So suppose $x<0<y.$ Then, using the MVT twice, we get

$$\tag 1 f(y) - f(x) = f(y)-f(0) + f(0) -f(x) = f'(c)(y-0) + f'(d)(0-x),$$

where $0<c<y, x<d<0.$ Because $f'(t) = 1/(1+t^2),$ each of $f'(c),f'(d) < 1.$ Thus $(1) < y + (-x) = y-x,$ and we're done.